# Why this is true using Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $g$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $K=k(C)$ the field of rational functions of $C$. Consider $P$ a point at $C$.

What I know:

For each $r\in \mathbb N$, we have $l(rP)\le l((r+1)P)$, because we have the following inequality betweeen these divisors: $rP\le(r+1)P$.

I'm trying to understand this claim:

> l(0)=1 and by Riemann-Roch theorem we have $l\big((2g-1)P\big)=g$. So
>   if $N_r\doteqdot N_r(P)=l(rP)$, then we have $1=N_0\le N_1\le\ldots\le
>  N_{2g-1}=g$.

What I didn't understand is why $N_{2g-1}=g$, i.e., why $l\big((2g-1)P\big)=g$.

**Riemann-Roch theorem:**

Let $W$ be a canonical divisor over a curve $C$ of genus $g$. Then, for every divisor $D$, we have

$$l(D)=\deg(D)+1-g+l(W-D)$$

I really need help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that it follows from Riemann-Roch Theorem that $$l(D) = deg(D) + 1 - g$$ if $deg(D) \geq 2g-1$.

Skecthing the proof, if you have $h \in l(W-D)-\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ then $(h) \geq D-W$ and it follows that $$0 = deg((h)) \geq deg(D-W) > 0$$

which is a contradiction.

Take $D = (2g -1)P$ and you will have the result.

Comment: Why do we have $deg((h))=0$ in the first equality?

Comment: You have that $(h)$ is a principal divisor and $(h) = (h)_0 - (h)_\infty$.

Comment: So every principal divisor has zero degree?

Comment: Yes, if $f \in K-\lbrace 0\rbrace$ then $deg ((f)) = 0$, where $(f)$ is a principal divisor.

Comment: You need to remember that  the degree of a divisor of a function $f \in X$, where $X$ is a smooth algebraic variety, is the sum of all zeroes of $f$ counted with multiplicity minus the sum of all poles of $f$ also counted with multiplicity.

Comment: So when I use the fact $\deg(D)\ge 2g-1$?

Comment: I've studied this under algebraic curves, so for example I used to take $D= w \in S_{K|\mathbb{R}}$ where $S_{K|\mathbb{R}}$ is the Riemann Surface over the field $K$ and $w$ a valuation function. The value of $deg(w)$ would allow me to conclude certain properties for instance over $S_{K|\mathbb{R}}$ without any rational points with genus $g=0$ would have $deg(w) = 2 > 2.0 - 1$, and so on

Comment: It's too much to explain it all here

Comment: And $deg (w)$ was seen as a dimension of a field extension, for the record.

Comment: yes, I've just found this claim in a book of algebraic function fields, you're right. Do you think I can find this result with a more classical demonstration like the ones in Fulton's book for example? thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure, I used [Stichtenoth](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-76877-7) but I'm afraid it has nothing classical about it, and I've also used notes from my professor. The book you referred is William Fulton - Algebraic Curves? As for the proof is just that, nothing else.

Comment: yes, I'm using this book also from Stichtenoth, great book btw. Yes, it's algebraic curves from Fulton

Comment: Yes it is, I really enjoy this subject, it's hard to find someone studying it here in my university, I hope I could help.

Comment: It's hard to find someone studying it in my university also. Of course you helped, many thanks!